# Function to find the smallest prime x and the biggest m = power_of(x) such that n % m = 0 and n % x = 0?

Tags: c++, primes

**Given m integer from 1 to m, for each 1 <=i <= m find the smallest prime x that `i % x = 0` and the biggest number y which is a power of x such that `i % y = 0`**

My main approach is : 
I use Eratos agorithm to find x for every single m like this :
I use set for more convenient track

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
set<int> s;
void Eratos() {
    while(!s.empty()) {
        int prime = *s.begin();
        s.erase(prime);
        X[prime] = prime;
        for(int j = prime * 2; j <= L ; j++) {
            if(s.count(j)) {
                  int P = j / prime;
                  if( P % prime == 0) Y[j] =  Y[P]*prime;
                  else Y[j] = prime;
            }
        }
    }
signed main() {
     for(int i = 2; i<= m; i++) s.insert(i);
     Eratos();
     for(int i = 1; i <= m; i++) cout << X[m] << " " << Y[m] ;
 }
```

with `X[m]` is the number x corresponding to m and same as `Y[m]`
But it seems not really quick and optimal solution. And the memory request for this is so big and when m is 1000000. I get MLE. So is there an function that can help to solve this problem please. Thank you so much.

Comment: We could use a [mre], so include enough code so that we can compile this. (What is `s`?)  Include sample data to run with that shows the problem.  [Edit] the question to explain what you mean by `x | i`.

Comment: Note: the syntax `x | i` is math notation for `x` divides `i` (i.e. `i` is divisible by `x`)

Comment: I've updated it please read again. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: According to your title, you have "...such that m|n".  Please clarify "m|n".  There is no "n" in your question nor in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of simply marking a number prime/not-prime in the original Sieve of Eratosthenes, save the corresponding smallest prime factor which divides that number.
Once that's done, the biggest power of the smallest prime of a number would mean to simply check how many times that smallest prime appears in the prime factorization of that number which is what the nested for loop does in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void SoE(vector<int>& sieve)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < sieve.size(); i += 2)
        sieve[i] = 2;
    for (int i = 3; i < sieve.size(); i += 2)
        if (sieve[i] == 0)
            for (int j = i; j < sieve.size(); j += i)
                if(sieve[j] == 0)
                    sieve[j] = i;
}

int main()
{
    int m;
    cin >> m;

    vector<int> sieve(m + 1, 0);
    SoE(sieve);

    for (int i = 2; i < sieve.size(); ++i)
    {
        int x, y;

        x = y = sieve[i];
        for (int j = i; sieve[j / x] == x; j /= x)
            y *= x;
        cout << x << ' ' << y << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you're trying to do but I understand that you're trying to use Sieve of Eratosthenes to find prime numbers. Well, what you probably need is a bitset, it's like a boolean array but uses bits instead of bytes which means it uses less memory. Here's what I did:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

vector<int> primes;

int main()
{
    const int m = 1e7;
    bitset<m> bs;

    int limit = (int) sqrt (m);
    for (int i = 2; i < limit; i++) {
        if (!bs[i]) {
            for (int j = i * i; j < m; j += i)
                bs[j] = 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 2; i < m; i++) {
        if (!bs[i]) {
            primes.push_back (i);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wondering is there a function that can calculate this as fast as possible